# openpyxl delete rows from formatted table / error referencing table

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to delete rows from a formatted table in Excel using the `delete_rows()` method. However, this does not delete the rows but only the content of the cells.

As an info, you can format a range as table using openpyxl as described in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet_tables.html

I have a formatted table called *Table5* in the worksheet *Sheet1*:

[image]

To delete 2 rows from row 5, I use the following commands:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws.delete_rows(5, 2) # this is the delete command
wb.save('data.xlsx')
```

With the command `delete_rows()`, the range of the formatted table remains till row 6, whereas it shrinks when I delete the rows directly in Excel.

[image]

The question: How do I delete properly both the data and the formatted range?

Corollary note:

Also when I insert data, the table range does not expand. For example:

```
for i in range(4, 9):
    ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = i - 1
    ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value = (i - 1) * 100
```

The range stays the same i.e. till row 6, whereas the range expands automatically by inserting data into Excel manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the linked doc, you must have:

1. added data to the `Worksheet`
2. created a `Table` instance which covers the data (`ref=A1:B6`)
3. added the `Table` instance to the worksheet with `ws.add_table`.

When you later add or remove rows, this does not affect the table which was remains with `ref=A1:B6`.

You would need to change the `Table` instance's `ref` to fit the new data layout.

```py
# access your table (subsitute <Table> for the name of your table)
tab = ws.tables[<Table>]

# change the ref
tab.ref = "A1:B4"

# and save
wb.save('data.xlsx')
```

**NB.** the interface to the `tables` has changed since version 3.0.0, this code is tested with for `3.0.10`, please check with documentation for previous/further changes.

Comment: Indeed, I followed the three steps from the doc as you said. Apparently, in my version 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'tables'. I am using openpyxl==3.0.0 - not sure that the current version (3.0.10 as of today) has changed the method so radically.

Comment: The object `ws._tables` is a list that contains the tables. In the sheet, there is only one table, so `ws._tables[0]` contains the formatted table. Then, you can change the reference with `ws._tables[0].ref = "A1:B4"` and save.

Comment: Looks like table retrieval by name was added as part of [3.0.4](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#id41).

Comment: This is a useful piece of information. Then, I need an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I expand the answer by *ljmc* (which I have accepted) containing both ways with the newer and the older version of `openpyxl`.

After upgrading to `openpyxl==3.0.10`, you change the reference of a formatted table by simply referencing to the table name in the worksheet with the attribute `.tables`. Example: in the worksheet *Sheet1* there is a formatted table named *Table5*:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws.delete_rows(5, 2) # this is the delete command
ws.tables['Table5'].ref = "A1:B4" # change the reference
wb.save('data.xlsx')
```

As simple as that: because `ws.tables['Table5']` contains the formatted table.

Before the upgrade (`openpyxl==3.0.0`) you reference the formatted table using the method using the `._tables` attribute, but instead of the name *Table5* you need the index:

```
ws.delete_rows(5, 2) # this is the delete command
ws._tables[0].ref = "A1:B4" # change the reference
```

Using `[0]` works only if you have one formatted table in your worksheet or if *Table5* is the first within the table object.

The proper pythonic way is to first determine the index where *Table5* is in the table object:

```
ws.delete_rows(5, 2) # this is the delete command
ix = next(i for i, t in enumerate(ws._tables) if t.displayName == "Table5")
ws._tables[ix].ref = "A1:B4"  # change the reference
```